# For either Libreoffice or Word, how do I insert chapter and scene fields?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, libreoffice

I am writing a play, and I want to be able to insert two fields, much like Page #. Let me explain...

Each time Scene 1, Scene 2, Scene 3, etc., I want the pages in that particular field to be named after it. So, Scene 2 would be 15 pages, and it would have a 2 on each of those pages. Then on Scene 3, it would have 20 pages, and I want each of those pages with a 3.

Also, I want to do this for Act I and II. For each page in Act I, I want the roman numeral I. For each page in Act II, I want the Roman numeral II.

So basically, I want to insert fields for both of these. Thanks.

Comment: In Word, check out the embedded help for fields{}.

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice, go to `Tools -> Outline Numbering`.  For `Number`, select "I, II, III, ..."  For the `Before` separator, enter "Act" plus a space.

Then select level 2.  For `Number`, select "1, 2, 3, ..."  For the `Before` separator, enter "Scene" plus a space.  Change `Show sublevels` to 1.  Press OK to close.

Now to enter an act heading, on a blank line, choose the heading 1 style.  (If it helps, press space to be the heading name.)  To enter a scene heading, choose the heading 2 style.

In the footer, go to `Insert -> Fields -> More Fields` and choose the Document tab.  Under Type, click `Chapter`, and double click `Chapter number` to insert it.  Change the level to 2 and then double click `Chapter number` again to insert it.

The result is that it will say something like `Act I Scene 1` at the bottom of every page, with the numbers changing according to act and scene.

See https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Inserting_a_Chapter_Name_and_Number_in_a_Header_or_a_Footer.

Comment: All it does is give a black space when I present insert. I followed these directions awhile back and it didn't help...

Comment: It just gives a grey box

Comment: Probably it is giving a grey box because there is nothing set to `Heading 1`.  First in the document press enter to create an empty line, then in the style drop-down box, select `Heading 1`.  Does it make the line change to "Act I"?

Comment: Ok, I was able to do it, but now I have another issue. I want the heading to be in Courier 12 font and centered horizontally.

Comment: Click the down arrow of the style drop-down box, then click on the down arrow next to `Heading 1`.  Choose `Edit Style`.  In the `Font` tab, choose font and size, and in the `Alignment` tab, choose center.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to edit it, but i say for it to use underline but it doesn't.

Comment: In `Font Effects` tab, set underline to single, then press OK.  If it doesn't show the underline, select the text and go to `Format -> Clear Direct Formatting` in the main menu.  Now it will show the underline.

Comment: I did clear direct formatting and it still didn't show the underline

Comment: What happens if you select the text and then press the underline button in the toolbar (or press Ctrl+U)?  If it shows the underline, then you can select the text and choose `Update To Match Selection` in the style drop-down box.

Comment: Ok, I think I am figuring stuff out, but I have one last issue.

I was able to put Act I and Scene 1 down, but my question is... 

How I do make the A line up with the S?

I put both in center but the A is not lined up with the S.

ACT
Scene

for example, see how A and S line up?

Comment: To line up "A" on one line with "S" on the line below, use a table.  Center the table, and then left-align the text inside each cell.

Comment: How do I insert the number for Scene, I change level but it makes no difference...

Comment: `Tools -> Outline Numbering`, select Level 2, change Number to `1, 2, 3, ...`   Then press OK.  Now enter a new line and choose the `Heading 2` style in the style drop-down box.  It will show the number in the text.

Comment: Press Enter to go to the next line.  Then `Insert -> Fields -> More Fields`.  In the `Document` tab, change the Level to 2, then double-click `Chapter Number`.  It should show a grey box saying `Scene 1`.

Comment: It doesn't show it. I am able to get the Act to show properly though but not scenes.

BAsically I just want the number for the scenes.

Comment: What does the `Heading 2` text say?

Comment: Ok, it works, there is just a problem, it does not recognize that i have the scene on the page. For example, scene 1 starts on page 1 but it just says I. Then scene 2 starts on page 10, but it still says 1. Only on a page 11 it says 2.

Comment: Try saving and closing the document.  Then on page 1, temporarily insert another `Heading 2`, making it scene 2.  On page 2, insert another `Heading 2`, making it scene 3.  Now see if it starts updating correctly.

Comment: Also: "To update all of the fields in a document, press F9, or choose Edit - Select All, and then press F9."  https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/About_Fields

Comment: I give up. When I save in different formats, the whole header-footer thing messes up. I actually prefer Word because I have to email this in word, but saving it from libreoffice into word format messes up the header system

Comment: Yes, you should save in ODT format to make it work properly.  Can you email a PDF file instead of an MS Word format?

Comment: Oh yeah, I can submit it in PDF.

Comment: Good, then it should work correctly.  Just do `File -> Export as PDF`.  LibreOffice has excellent PDF support.

Comment: My headings aren''t able to be underlined...